# Why don't these regular expressions match the same?

Tags: regex

Given the string `12312112211212123`
I can't understand why the following regex: `(1.+)\1` matches

But this one doesn't: `((1.+)\1)`

What is the explanation for this?

Comment: for better visualization visit https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 4):

The second regex doesn't match, because the outer group is seen as group 1 and the inner group as group 2. To make it match, you would have to use `((1.+)\2)`.

Comment: That, or `(?:(1.+)\1)`

Answer (score 2):

`\1` refers to the first set of parentheses in the expression.

Think about it.